# How to change key name in ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

this is my sample data

```
id: 5
isAchievementEnabled: false
isTargetFormEnabled: true
name: "NFSM - Pulse"
odiyaName: "Pulse or"
```

my `ng-multiselect-dropdown` picking name key to show. But i want when my `this.language==='or'`, it should select `odiyaName` key instead of `name` key. How can i do this?

> html

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
              [data]="schemes"
              [placeholder]="'Select Schemes'"
              (onSelect)="onSchemesChanged($event,false)"
              (onDeSelect)="onSchemesChanged($event,false)"
              (onSelectAll)="onSchemesChanged($event,true)"
              (onDeSelectAll)="onSchemesChanged($event,true)"
              [settings]="dropdownSettings"
              [disabled]="enableSchemes ? null : true"
              formControlName="subSchemeIds">
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

> ts

```
getSubSchemes(masterComponentGroupId) {
    this.schemesService.getSubSchemes({
      page: -1,
      orderby: 'scheme_id',
      order: 'asc',
      masterComponentGroupId: masterComponentGroupId
    }).subscribe(data => {
      this.enableSchemes = true;
      this.schemes = data.items;
      if(this.language==='en')
      {
        //console.log('hello en');
      }
      if(this.language==='or')
      {
        //console.log('hello or');
      }
      console.log("this.scheme",this.schemes);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. After you change `textField` you need to pass `data` again as a new array, as this lib use OnPush strategy.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Hanoi' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Lang Son' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Vung Tau' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Hue' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'Cu Chi' }
    ];
    // setting and support i18n
    this.settings = {
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      
    };
  }



public changeLabelKey() {
    // async, in your case can be request to get language
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.settings = {...this.settings, textField: 'item_id'};
      this.data = [{ item_id: 1, item_text: 'Test' }];
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-lylzrm)